# Nested GLMMs: which are my random factors?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, random-variable, random-effects-model, glmm, lme4-nlme

I am analyzing the number of seed capsules between different genotypes (A,B and C) I have 4 replicates for each genotype and in each of these replicates, I have 8 plants. Here is an example of the data:

```
Genotype,replicate_ID,Plant_ID,seed_capsules
A,1,1,100
A,1,2,50
A,1,3,60
B,2,1,100
B,2,2,40
B,2,3,30
C,3,1,10
C,3,2,100
C,3,3,90
```

I used `glmer` on the data but I am not sure whether my random variable is the replicate_ID or the plant_ID or both. Here is an example of what I tried so far:

```
freplicate_ID <- factor(data$replicate_ID) 
fplant_ID <- factor(data$plant_ID)
m5 <- glmer(seed_capsules ~ pop_ID + (1| freplicate_ID /fplant_ID), family=poisson,data = data)
```

Further, how do I obtain the diagnostic plots for such a model? How do I compare between the genotypes? Do I need to run `lsmeans` on the model? Like this for example:

```
lsmeans(m5,pairwise ~ pop_ID, data=data)
```